# Web Push Notification: iOS not showing notification

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I encountered a problem that iOS iPhone does not display my notifications sent by me from the server. iPhone 11 pro max iOS 16.6.
push comes to the console, but is not displayed as a notification.
I receive the endpoint, token, public and private keys

**Html/JS**

```
        async function push() {
            let push_notification;
            let publicKey;
            let serverkey;
            let endpoint;
            let p256dh;
            let auth;

            push_notification = document.getElementById('push_notification');

            if (push_notification.checked) {
                await navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(async (reg) => {
                    await $.ajax({
                        url: "/backend/message/push_vapid/",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {
                            "data": "data"
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $("#louder").css({
                                "display": "none"
                            });
                        },
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $("#louder").css({
                                "display": "block"
                            });
                        },
                        success: function(result) {
                            $("#louder").css({
                                "display": "none"
                            });
                            publicKey = result['keys'][0]['publicKey']; //here i get the public key
                        }
                    });

                    await window.Notification.requestPermission();
                    await reg.pushManager.subscribe({
                        userVisibleOnly: true,
                        applicationServerKey: publicKey
                    }).then(async (subscription) => {

                        endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
                        p256dh = subscription.toJSON().keys.p256dh;
                        auth = subscription.toJSON().keys.auth;

                        await $.ajax({
                            url: "/backend/message/save_endpoint_user/",
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            data: {
                                "endpoint": endpoint,
                                "p256dh": p256dh,
                                "auth": auth
                            },
                            error: function(err) {
                                alert('error', err)
                                $("#louder").css({
                                    "display": "none"
                                });
                            },
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                $("#louder").css({
                                    "display": "block"
                                });
                            },
                            success: function(result) {
                                $("#louder").css({
                                    "display": "none"
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        await reg.showNotification('OpenSoul', {
                            body: 'Push activated!'
                        });
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                });

                await $.ajax({
                    url: "/backend/settings/notification/",
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        "try": "try"
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        $("#louder").css({
                            "display": "none"
                        });
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#louder").css({
                            "display": "block"
                        });
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#louder").css({
                            "display": "none"
                        });
                        window.location = "/backend/settings/";
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

**Vapid keys**

```
$vapid = VAPID::createVapidKeys();
$publicKey = $vapid['publicKey'];
$privateKey = $vapid['privateKey'];

$res = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET publicKey='$publicKey', privateKey='$privateKey' WHERE id='$user_id'");

$arr = array();
$key = 0;
$res1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT publicKey,privateKey FROM users WHERE id='$user_id' LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
    $publicKey_us    = $row['publicKey'];

    $arr[$key]['publicKey']    = (string) $publicKey_us;
}

$json = array(
    "keys" => $arr,
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

**Then I store the data in the database**

```
if(!empty($_POST['endpoint']) && !empty($_POST['p256dh']) && !empty($_POST['auth'])) {

    $endpoint = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['endpoint']);
    $p256dh = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['p256dh']);
    $auth = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['auth']);

    $res = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET endpoint='$endpoint', p256dh='$p256dh', auth='$auth' WHERE id='$user_id'");
    header("HTTP/1.1 200");

} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 400");
}
```

**sending a message from the server to the user**

```
        $push = [
            'subscription' => Subscription::create([
                'endpoint' => $endpoint,
                'keys' => [
                    'p256dh' => $p256dh,
                    'auth' => $auth
                ]
            ]),
            'payload' => json_encode([
                'title' => "Name my site",
                'body' => "$name_user_id: $mess",
                'data' => [
                    'vibrate' => [100, 200],
                    'additionalData' => [],
                    'url' => "My site",
                ],
            ]),
        ];

        $auth = [
            'VAPID' => [
                'subject' => '@gmail.test',
                'publicKey' => $publicKey,
                'privateKey' => $privateKey,
            ],
        ];

        $webPush = new WebPush($auth);

        try {
            $webPush->queueNotification(
                $push['subscription'],
                $push['payload']
            );
            $report = $webPush->flush()->current();
            $is_success = $report->isSuccess();
            $response = $report->getResponseContent();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $is_success = false;
            $response = $th->getMessage();
        }
```

**SW.js**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    let pushMessageJSON = event.data.json();
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(pushMessageJSON.title, {
            body: pushMessageJSON.body,
            icon: pushMessageJSON.icon,
            vibrate: pushMessageJSON.data.vibrate,
            data: {
                additionalData: pushMessageJSON.data.additionalData,
                url: pushMessageJSON.data.url,
            },
        }),
    );
    console.log("PUSH!::", event,pushMessageJSON.body);
});


self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    let url = event.notification.data.url;
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(url)
    );
}, false);

self.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    // A message has been sent to this service worker.
    console.log("sw Handling message event:", event);
});

self.addEventListener('pushsubscriptionchange', function (event) {
    // The Push subscription ID has changed. The App should send this
    // information back to the App Server.
    console.log("sw Push Subscription Change", event);
    event.waitUntil(
        self.clients.matchAll()
            .then(clientList => {
                let sent = false;
                console.debug("Service worker found clients",
                    JSON.stringify(clients));
                clientList.forEach(client => {
                    console.debug("Service worker sending to client...", client);
                    sent = true;
                    client.postMessage({'type': 'update'});
                });
                if (sent == false) {
                    throw new Error("No valid client to send to.");
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("Service worker couldn't send message: ", err);
            })
    );

});

self.addEventListener('registration', function (event) {
    // The service worker has been registered.
    console.log("sw Registration: ", event);
});

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
    console.log("sw Install: ", JSON.stringify(event));
});
  
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    console.log("sw activate: ", JSON.stringify(event));
});
```

*This code works fine on firefox, google chrome, android.
The problem is only with iOS iPhone and Mac OS. However, in the console I tested in mac os sw.js 'push' sees the message but does not display it as a notification on the screen. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?*

I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong. It seems that this code works on Android and should work on iPhone

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).